# Image processing LabVIEW and myrio

Tags: image-processing, labview, vision, assistant

i want a good tutorial or courses to start learning image processing in LabVIEW using myrio and Vision Assistant

To detect a object and send the end effector of the delta robot to it

Answer (score 2):

This guide talks about myRIO and the Vision Assistant as well as LabVIEW based machine vision applications.

Google "NI myRIO Vision Essentials Guide"
or go here
http://www.ni.com/white-paper/52475/en/

I also suggest the machine vision course NI offers. It won't have anything on RIO, but machine vision is a big subject and NI has done a lot of work to make PC development and RIO development similar.

http://sine.ni.com/tacs/app/overview/p/ap/of/lang/en/pg/1/sn/n8:11603,n24:1324/id/1586/